# How can I pass object as a parameter to a method expecting list?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a

```
class response{
    private list<Tlist> tlist= new arrayist<Tlist>

    ...getters
    ...setters
}
```

I have another

```
class Tlist{
    private String name
    private String address
}
```

I have a controller class where I need to pass the object of Tlist into the setter method of

i.e `response.setTlist(tlist)`

Actually `setTlist` is not accepting the object of Tlist class. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Dont explain what your code is (not) doing. Post code instead.

Comment: Please don't write "pseudo" code. If it is `Java` related please write `Java`. Code in your question above does not even compile!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you shall change

```
private list<Tlist> tlist= new arrayist<object>
```

to

```
private java.util.List<Tlist> tList= new java.util.Arrayist<>();
```

and then use your custom setter as :

```
public void setTlist(Tlist tList) {
    this.tList = tList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTlist()` expects a `List` object e.g. an `ArrayList` of `Tlist` objects. So you cannot pass a single `Tlist` (tlist) object to it. How about trying to pass:

```
List<Tlist> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(tlist);
response.setTlist(list);
```

Comment: So,I need to create a new list and then add the items in tlist object to the new list and pass the new list to the setter method?

Comment: Yes I think so. Please try to use better names, e.g. you have a class named `Tlist` and an object reference `tlist` but they are not the same. `tlist` is an `ArrayList` not a `Tlist` reference. This can lead you to mistakes like trying to use the setter `setTlist` which requires an `ArrayList` object (or any `List` implementation) and not a `Tlist` object.